# Accessing Node of an XML object

Tags: php, xml, object

I am trying to access certain pieces of data from an xml file, here is the problem.

```
###XML FILE
<products>
    <product>
        ....
        ....
    </product>
    <product>
        ....
        ....
    </product>
    etc...
</products>
```

I know that the piece of data I need is in (`$products->product->myProdNode`) I have this mapping (and many others) stored in my database as a string e.g.'`product->prodCode`' or  '`product->dedscriptions->short_desc`' How can I access this data by using the strings stored in my database.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you replace your -> with forward slash (/), they effectively become Xpath and you can query Node contents like that.

E.g

```
'product->dedscriptions->short_desc' should be mapped to
'product/dedscriptions/short_desc'
```

Please read more on Xpath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

E.g. In C#

XmlNode.SelectSingleNode("product/dedscriptions/short_desc").InnerText will get the short description text

In [php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

$result = $record->xpath('descriptions/short_description');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'Results is: ',$node,"\n";
}

Comment: How would i get the data with this method?

Comment: $record->xpath('descriptions/short_description'); - I want just the value not the SimpleXMLElement Object

Comment: Am not sure about the properties and methods of SimpleXMLElement Object, but you should access the inner text or value